# How to set scroll bar precision

Tags: qt

The scrollbar in my application is just taking 2 positions and nothing in between, that make it look silly to be honest... is there a way to raise its precision?

[image]

First position

[image]

Second position

Comment: Are you using a `QTableView`?  If so then that, as far as I recall, is the expected behaviour -- horizontal scrolling is on a per-column basis rather than per-pixel.

Comment: yes That was it thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#horizontalScrollMode-prop There you can set `QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel`

Answer (score 0):

The answer of V.K. is correct, I just want to give you the link to the current release document for Qt 5 to [setHorizontalScrollMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#horizontalScrollMode-prop) and use as parameter `QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel`